# Проверить текст на соответствие числа открывающихся и закрывающихся скобок

Tags: c, файлы

Дан текстовый файл, содержащий программу на языке Си. Проверить эту программу на соответствие числа открывающихся и закрывающихся скобок (круглых, квадратных, фигурных и угловых).
Данная программа в любых случаях выдает, что скобки расставлены правильно, даже если это не так. А если написать `feof(f)` вместо `EOF`, файл вообще не читается. Помогите найти ошибку

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("file.txt","r");
    char s = fgetc(f);
    int kr=0, kv=0, fg=0, ug=0;
    if(f==NULL)
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл");
    while (!EOF)
    {
        if(s=='(')
            kr++;
        if(s==')')
            kr--;
        if(s=='[')
            kv++;
        if(s==']')
            kv--;
        if(s=='{')
            fg++;
        if(s=='}')
            fg--;
        if(s=='<')
            ug++;
        if(s=='>')
            ug--;
    }
    if(kr==0)
        printf("Число открывающихся и закрывающихся круглых скобок равно\n");
    else
        printf("Число открывающихся и закрывающихся круглых скобок не равно\n");
    if(kv==0)
        printf("Число открывающихся и закрывающихся квадратных скобок равно\n");
    else
        printf("Число открывающихся и закрывающихся квадратных скобок не равно\n");
    if(fg==0)
        printf("Число открывающихся и закрывающихся фигурных скобок равно\n");
    else
        printf("Число открывающихся и закрывающихся фигурных скобок не равно\n");
    if(ug==0)
        printf("Число открывающихся и закрывающихся угловых скобок равно\n");
    else
        printf("Число открывающихся и закрывающихся угловых скобок не равно\n");
    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
```

}

Comment: Что значить "соответствие числа"? Вот тут `)(` есть идеальное "соответствие числа". Это считается правильно или неправильно? А вот `!EOF` - это полный бред. Также чтения файла в цикле я в упор не вижу. Вы жалуетесь, что "файл вообще не читается". Так а где чтение файла-то в программе???

Comment: @AnT чтение файла в char s = fgetc(f); и while (!EOF). Почему !EOF бред?

Comment: Это не "чтение файла", а чтение только первого символа файла. А остальной файл кто читать будет??? А ваш `!EOF` - чушь хотя бы потому, что `EOF` - это *константа*. Никакого отношения к состоянию вашего файла она сама по себе не имеет и иметь не может. Посмотрите хоть примеры того, как правильно использовать `EOF` c `fgetc` вместо того, чтобы на равном месте изобретать чепуху.

Comment: Непонятно также, почему чтение первого символа файла делается ДО проверки на успешность открытия файла. Что за логика тут работала???

Comment: Если изменить чтение на while ((s=fgetc(f))!=EOF), то это будет правильным или же здесь все еще читается только первый символ? Если так, то каким образом осуществить чтение всего файла и как все же обозначить конец файла?

Comment: Так - правильно, но переменная `s` должна иметь тип `int`, а не `char`. Если вы не понимаете, что это - принципиально отличается от вашего исходного варианта, то вам надо сначала пойти элементарные книжки по языку С почитать. А пытаться писать код, не понимая таких вещей - бесполезно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Много ошибок в коде у Вас.

1. Вы получаете файловый дескриптор f и **сразу** должны проверить его на NULL, а не считать первый символ строки, а потом проверить на NULL.
   Правильно так:

   ```
   f=fopen("file.txt","r");
   if(f==NULL)
   {
       printf("Не удалось открыть файл");
       return;
   }

   char s = fgetc(f);
   ```
2. У вас цикл `while` никогда не выполнится, т.к. EOF - это константа, которая не равна 0 и результат выражения `!EOF` всегда будет false. И в самом цикле вы не считываете следующий символ из файла, что приведет к бесконечному циклу. Правильно будет так:

   ```
   // Убрать строку char s = fgetc(f);

   while ( (s = fgetc(f) ) != EOF)
   {
       // Проверки для символа s
   }
   ```

Основные ошибки программы я указал, надеюсь, Вам поможет это. Если Вам не нужно проверять, правильно ли закрыты скобки (например, ваша программа на текст `))((` будет выдавать положительный результат), то больше ничего изменять не потребуется.

Comment: Иногда имеет смысл делать `err(1, "msg");` вместо `return;`. А считывать из файла лучше блочно, конечно, хотя ОС и сама по умолчанию кэширует странички. Вообще, по-хорошему, файлы надо `mmap()`-ом открывать.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к проблемам с файлом я думаю, что ([)] - это верная последовательность, так что по-моему правильность скобок нужно проверять при помощи стека, примерно так:

```
#define  STACK_SIZE  1000
char stk[STACK_SIZE];
stk[0] = '*';     // Для сообщения о "недополнении" стека
int p = 1;
while((s = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
{
    switch(s)
    {
    case '(':
    case '{':
    case '[':
        stk[p++] = s; break;
    case ')':
        {
            if (stk[--p] != '(')
            {
                puts("Error unmatched ')'");
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    case '}':
        {
            if (stk[--p] != '{')
            {
                puts("Error unmatched '}'");
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    case ']':
        {
            if (stk[--p] != '[')
            {
                puts("Error unmatched ']'");
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (p == STACK_SIZE)
    {
        puts("Переполнение стека"); return 1;
    }
}
if (p > 1)
{
    puts("Имеются незакрытые скобки");
    return 1;
}
```